# Using Flexbox, have elements stretch to fill gap between rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I feel a little silly asking this, but I've sort of exhausted my knowledge of Flexboxes, so I'm hoping maybe someone else can come in and help me out here.

My overall goal is to just have the two items in the middle row stretch to fill the space between the header and the items, and I have searched around and honestly can't figure out what it is that I should do. I forked the code from the [CSS Tricks Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), the one at the very bottom, and I've made some alterations. The code I currently have is (*open it in full screen mode to make it more clear*):

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.header {
  background: tomato;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
}
.main {
  text-align: left;
  align-self: stretch;
  background: deepskyblue;
}
.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}
.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1 auto;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex: 3 0px;
  }
  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .main {
    order: 2;
  }
  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .footer {
    order: 4;
  }
}
body {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <article class="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>

  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Is it possible in flexbox to achieve this **without changing the HTML**, or should I just look for another way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: @Ced It's a very close duplicate, despite *trivial differentiations* which can *easily be implemented* with a little thought.

Comment: @Ced Would you like to have a reading contest? I'll probably win. User Jhecht wants to know how to make children elements of a flex container stretch to fill the remaining horizontal width. This is answered in the dupe I linked, which asks for--wait for it--how to stretch children of a flex container to fill horizontal width.

Comment: Do you want the middle items to stretch all available height, pinning the header to the top and the footer to the bottom of the container? Or do you just want to close the gaps between rows?

Comment: @Michael_B I would like for the yellow/ blue items to stretch from where they currently are to the bottom of the header row. I'd like to do this without changing the HTML.

Comment: Just add `align-content: flex-start` to the container.

Comment: then the elements do not keep that bottom line -- the entire thing moves up.

Comment: All the stuff you put back from the edit are not relevant to the question and clutter up the code. What's the point in using prefixes for two flex properties, but not all the rest?

Comment: @Michael_B that's what came out of the SCSS parser -- I have no idea as I was just using Codepen to do it. That's also how I write, and while I understand you may not particularly enjoy it I don't like having my words changed.

Comment: It's not about me. The idea was to make your question easier to read and more attractive to answer. Again, using prefixes on just some flex properties and not others is kind of pointless. And in terms of your personal stories, they're just a distraction to people who simply want to focus on your coding problem.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that 20 or so words would have broken someone's interest in my question.

Comment: @Jhecht Thanks for the question, I found it great and that why I got a lil mad in the comment section when someone said it was a dupe. Plz check my answer, I spent a good while doing it.

Comment: I was wondering what happened as one (or maybe a few?) of your comments weren't there when I came back to the computer.

Comment: @Jhecht Posted an answer. Please give me your feedback on it.

Comment: As far as I know, **no**, it's not possible to get this result without changes in the markup

Comment: @vals Since header and footer has fixed height it is doable :) .... doable != recommended

Comment: @LGSon I mean, letting the flex do the layout... Of course you can always calculate the height by yourself (as in kukkuz answer, or your own)

Comment: Technically this question is asking how to accomplish this **without changing the HTML,** but this difference is still quite trivial, and can be implemented.

Comment: @Michael_B I disagree this question being a duplicate, what's your opinion? ... If you agree, I will reopen it, if not, why am I wrong it is not?

Comment: @LGSon, after reading both questions and all answers, I think it would be more useful for that question to be closed as a duplicate of this one.  Forwarding people from this question to that one wouldn't be helpful; this post offers a great deal more information.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks ... sounds like a good solution, I'll make the swap

Answer (score 10):

While people are telling you how to resolve the issue, they are not telling you why you don't have the result you expected. I think it's partly because most of them missed the actual question. Which I found really interesting.

Let me get some things out of the way first :

**Flex-direction:**: For practical purpose it means the direction in which the items are displayed. However it's **not accurate**.

For now let's say that if the direction is set to row, it means that each item must have the height of the container and they should be put next to each other. In other words the container has to be considered a row and the item are the columns.

```css
.c{
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height:100px;
}
.c1{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background:gold;

}
.c2{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
    <div class="c1"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
</div>
```

I didn't specify an height, the items filled the height of the row and stacked against each others like columns.

---

When you specify an height the item will take the height you defined but that does not change the height of the row :

```css
.c{
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
.c1{
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 40px;
  background:gold;

}
.c2{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
    <div class="c1"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
</div>
```

The red cube still spawn the vertical space because the height of the row hasn't changed.

---

**flex grow**: the amount of **free space** distributed to the different items.

```css
.c{
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
  }

.c1{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background:gold;
  }

.c2{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background:red;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="c">
        <div class="c1">AAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
        <div class="c2"></div>
    </div>
```

Despite having the same flex-grow value, those two items aren't the same size, that is because the free space is distributed among them but the yellow rectangle was bigger to begin with.

---

First let's use **flex-wrap : wrap**:

```css
.c{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height:100px;
}
.c1{
  width:200px;
  background:gold;

}
.c2{
  width:200px;
  background:red;
}

.c3{
  width:100px;
  background:orange;

}
.c4{
  width:300px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
    <div class="c1"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c3"></div>
    <div class="c4"></div>
</div>
```

As we can see when we go beyond the amount of width available the items start under, effectively creating another row.

---

Now to address your question:

What if we took the example above and set the height of the first item ? Let's see:

```css
    .c{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 400px;
      height:100px;
    }
    .c1{
      width:200px;
      height: 30px;
      background:gold;

    }
    .c2{
      width:200px;
      background:red;
    }

    .c3{
      width:200px;
      background:orange;

    }
    .c4{
      width:200px;
      background:green;
    }
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="c1"></div>
  <div class="c2"></div>
  <div class="c3"></div>
  <div class="c4"></div>
</div>
```

Like in your snippet.

Let's see another example:

```css
        .c{
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          border: 1px solid black;
          width: 600px;
          height:100px;
        }
        .c1{
          width:400px;
          height: 35px;
          background:gold;

        }
        .c2{
          width:200px;
          background:red;
        }

        .c3{
          width:200px;
          background:orange;

        }
        .c4{
          width:200px;
          background:green;
        }
        .c5{
          width:200px;
          background:purple;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="c">
      <div class="c1"></div>
      <div class="c2"></div>
      <div class="c3"></div>
      <div class="c4"></div>
      <div class="c5"></div>
    </div>
```

1. yellow cube of 400px X 35px is put and spans 2 columns, then red cube of 200px is put and spans 1 column.
2. At this point all the rectangles have 0 height except the first one which has 35px.
3. The remaining vertical space is divided between the rows as to spawn the whole vertical space. Thus the remaining vertical space is 100-35 = 65px.
   divided in 2 rows = 32.5. The first row gets 35 + 32.5 and the second row gets 32.5px height.

Another example to make things clearer:

```css
    .c, .d{
              display: flex;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
              border: 1px solid black;
              width: 600px;
              height:100px;
            }

            .c1{
              flex-shrink: 0;
              width:400px;
              height: 0px;
              background:gold;

            }
            .c2{
              width:200px;
              background:red;
            }

            .c3{
              width:200px;
              background:orange;

            }
            .c4{
              width:200px;
              background:green;
            }
            .c5{
              width:200px;
              background:purple;
            }


            .d1{
              width:400px;
              height: 50px;
              background:gold;

            }
            .d2{
              width:200px;
              background:red;
            }

            .d3{
              width:200px;
              background:orange;

            }
            .d4{
              width:200px;
              background:green;
            }
            .d5{
              width:200px;
              background:purple;
            }
```

```html
First item has 0px height, the vertical space remaining (100px) is divided between the 2 rows. Both row have 50px height
        <div class="c">
          <div class="c1"></div>
          <div class="c2"></div>
          <div class="c3"></div>
          <div class="c4"></div>
          <div class="c5"></div>
        </div>

First item has 35px height, the vertical space remaining (65px) is divided between the 2 rows.
        <div class="d">
          <div class="d1"></div>
          <div class="d2"></div>
          <div class="d3"></div>
          <div class="d4"></div>
          <div class="d5"></div>
        </div>
```

To resolve this you can use `calc()` to calculate the other rows height like others suggested. The reason is that there is no more free vertical space to be shared.

```css
            .c{
              display: flex;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
              border: 1px solid black;
              width: 600px;
              height:100px;
            }
            .c1{
              width:400px;
              height: 35px;
              background:gold;

            }
            .c2{
              width:200px;
              background:red;
            }

            .c3{
              height:calc(100% - 35px);
              width:600px;
              background:green;

            }
```

```html
        <div class="c">
          <div class="c1"></div>
          <div class="c2"></div>
          <div class="c3"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: that is one hell of an answer right there.

Comment: @Jhecht ahah I spent more time than I should on this but this really intriged me ! lol

Answer (score 7):

The idea is to wrap them around a container and use `flex-grow:1;` on that container, this will make the container fill the space between the header and footer..

Then in the `@media` query, change the `flex-direction` of this container to `row`. This will make the `.main` and `aside` to come side by side on big screens.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction:column;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
}
.header {
  background: tomato;
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
.main {
  text-align: left;
  //align-self: stretch;
  background: deepskyblue;
  padding:10px;
}
.main p{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}
.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}
.container{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1 auto;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
  }
  .main {
    flex: 3 0px;
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink:0;
  }
  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink:0;
  }
  .main {
    order: 2;
  }
  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .footer {
    order: 4;
  }
}
body {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <div class="container">
  <article class="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
    </div>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this _without_ using the wrapping element?

Comment: I don't think there is because there are to boxes which have to grow. Let me try, give me 10. If I can swing that I'll let you know.

Comment: much obliged @kittyCat

Comment: If you can figure something out I'd be thankful, but if not know that I do appreciate your help. I marked kukkuz as correct simply because he did manage to get a working example without changing the HTML, but as explained in the comment I dislike using `calc()` unless absolutely necessary (though the project may end up needing to use it).

Comment: @Jhecht   Come on man, the answer you accepted was the exactly same as mine. He used a wrapping element too. Also his answer doesn't work in chrome anyway.

Comment: I'm on chrome and it's working for me

Comment: the yellow div is hiding behind the footer. look in the snippet, not by resizing the screen

Comment: yellow div should push the footer ideally, which it does not in that case. and it may cause you problems if your main div has much more content then just some text.

Comment: Hmm you are correct. this does present a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You *can't* fill the remaining space in the *cross-axis* direction when you are using a *wrapping* flexbox - I guess you need a *column* `flexbox` for that.

But you can do this as a *quick fix*:

1. Add `align-content: center` to the `flexbox` (for resetting the default `stretch` value)
2. Adjust the heights using `calc` (have removed the `body` padding and margin for illustration)

See demo below:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center; /* ADDED THIS */
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.header {
  background: tomato;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
}
.main {
  text-align: left;
  align-self: stretch;
  background: deepskyblue;
  height: calc(50vh - 90px); /* ADDED THIS */
}
.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
  height: calc(50vh - 90px); /* ADDED THIS */
}
.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1 auto;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex: 3 0px;
  }
  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
    height: calc(100vh - 160px); /* ADDED THIS */
  }
  .main {
    order: 2;
    height: calc(100vh - 160px); /* ADDED THIS */
  }
  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .footer {
    order: 4;
  }
}
body {
  /* padding: 2em;*/
  margin: 0; /* ADDED THIS */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <article class="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>

  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Using `calc` is *not very tidy* and you would want to use a *nested* `flexbox` here (if it is ok to change the html):

1. Add a *wrapper* for the `main` and `aside-1` and make it a *wrapping* `flexbox` in *row* direction
2. Add `flex: 1` to this *wrapper* to fill the vertical space between the `header` and `footer`

See demo below:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  /*-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;*/
  /*flex-flow: row wrap;*/
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  /*flex: 1 1 100%;*/
}
.header {
  background: tomato;
  height: 50px;
  /*flex: 1 1 100%;*/
}
.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 50px;
}
.main {
  text-align: left;
  align-self: stretch;
  background: deepskyblue;
}
.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
  flex: 1 auto;/* ADDED THIS */
}
.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}
.wrapper > section { /* ADDED THIS */
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1 auto;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex: 3 0px;
  }
  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .main {
    order: 2;
  }
  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .footer {
    order: 4;
  }
}
body {
  /*padding: 2em;*/
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <section>
    <article class="main">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </article>
    <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
  </section>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: So far this is definitely seeming the best answer. I'm fiddling with the actual HTML / CSS I plan on using to see if this works.

Comment: cool, let me know how it goes :)

Comment: To comment on why I marked this answer as accepted: It the second code snippet in particular ends up working best for the actual HTML -- I'm still fiddling with it (as I have to rewrite some of the other CSS in the project) but it works the best. I'd have _liked_ to leave the HTML alone (like the first snippet) but I too like to avoid using `calc()` unless necessary. Thanks very much kukkuz!

Comment: In the second demo–using chrome–the `.aside-1` element is behind the footer. Though adding `overflow: auto` to `,wrapper > *` shows that it can overflow correctly. `.main, .aside-1, .aside-2 { overflow: auto; }` would produce the same results for both examples.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that due to the length of the content I was using to fill space (wasn't long enough to notice it was going behind the footer)

Comment: @TinyGiant thanks... added `overflow: auto` to `section` - guess that fixes it?

Comment: @kukkuz I also added `overflow:auto` to the `.main` element to ensure the background colors follow the text (otherwise they stopped at the first render boundaries)

Comment: @Jhecht that sounds good :)

Answer (score 3):

After reading all the other answers, I decided to post my own.

I might have missed something already posted or misunderstood the question, though for me this should be the simplest solution, without any markup changed.

If this answers your question, I will add a short explanation why/how it works.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
}
.main {
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .header {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    order: -1;
  }
  .main {
    flex: 2;
  }
  .aside-1 {
    order: -1;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
  .footer {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}



/*  for styling  */
.wrapper {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
  background: tomato;
}
.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.main {
  background: deepskyblue;
}
.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <article class="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>

  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

If you were able to change the markup, here is a version of mine, with a much simpler code base than others have given, and also the header and footer is without a fixed height.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.innerwrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.main {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .innerwrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .aside-1 {
    order: -1;
  }
}



/*  for styling  */
.wrapper {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper > *:not(.innerwrapper),
.wrapper .innerwrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
  background: tomato;
}
.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.main {
  background: deepskyblue;
}
.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  
  <div class="innerwrapper">
    <article class="main">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </article>
  
    <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: It uses something very similar to kukkuz's answer from my understanding -- using the `calc()` css3 function.

Comment: @Jhecht Yes, it does, though properly combined with a flexbox column layout. May I ask why to not change markup?

Comment: Vanity mostly, Curiosity after that, and a mild attempt to not have to rewrite any jQuery.

Comment: @Jhecht Vanity is good, keep you on your toes :) ... but to stand on your toes to long might hurt. Added a 2:nd sample, which I recommend you chose, whether you pick my answer or not.